# Is it possible to remove part of an image (and the canvas) in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a web design in photoshop but it is too long. I'd like to remove a horizontal section from the middle. Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  One way is to select a rectangle of the lower part of the image which you want to preserve, then copy and paste it and move it so that it covers the middle section you don't want. You can then crop the whole image to the smaller size.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed there would be an easier way to do this.